# Facebook privacy policy invalid because we support https

Tags: facebook, curl, https, facebook-debugger

They say that we must check our privacy policy with curl. I tested this with Google's privacy policy to see what the fuss is about with http vs https. I believe the issue is that they are not following the redirects with -L. What should I do?

`curl http://policies.google.com/privacy` returns nothing

`curl https://policies.google.com/privacy`
returns the full privacy policy

`curl -L http://policies.google.com/privacy` returns the full privacy policy

Comment: I don't understand your question.  What is it that you're trying to do?

Comment: We received an email from Facebook that says we need an active privacy policy. One of the points said "Curl your privacy URL to ensure it returns a 200 OK."

Comment: Are your URL really https://policies.google.com/privacy ?

Comment: You don’t have to cURL this yourself, you can also simply use the Facebook debug tool. The Facebook scraper (or at least the same mechanism in the background) needs to be able to read this URL, because that is how Facebook “verifies” your privacy URL. (This is only about proper public reachability of the URL, not about the actual content of your policy.)

Comment: The debugger is not happy with the url for some reason @CBroe https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fzyamusic.com%2Fprivacy-policy

Comment: @WizKid no, the privacy policy is http://zyamusic.com/privacy-policy

Comment: That message is usually what you get when the whole domain has been blocked. Can you share this URL (or any other from that domain) on Facebook, or do you get an error saying something similar in that situation as well?

Comment: @CBroe I just tried posting the link of Facebook, and it states "Could not retrieve data from URL". I reported on the debugger site that I think this is an error, but I have no idea why the site is being blocked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We sent a note to Facebook and they fixed it. There really wasn't anything for us to do once the helpful people here pointed out the site was flagged.